# Defining "Window" in Google Maps JavaScript API v3?

Tags: google-maps-api

I am trying to use Google Maps Javascript API in a java application through Nashorn (basically lets you run javascript in java). Anyway when I load the API I get an error that "window" is not defined in the API.

Does anyone know where I might be able to find documentation on "window" or where in the API it might be defined?

Answer (score 1):

It wasn't actually a google maps API issue (which I couldn't tell from the console). Upon further inspection of Oracle's Nashorn documentation I found that Nashorn doesn't support 'objects normally supported in web-browsers' such as `window` and `console`. Well that is too bad.

For more information you can find it [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-nashorn-2126515.html), right before the section titled "Scripting Extensions".